# How to queue up calls to stored procedures in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, locking, jobs

I have a stored procedure in oracle (which schedules a one-time job to run another procedure, if this is relevant). The job calls another stored procedure which runs for a few minutes, and performs inserts updates and deletes and also uses loops. Now while the long procedure is running, if there is another call for it to run, is it possible to prevent them from executing simultaneously? And even better, to make the second one execute once the previous one has finished, like queue them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent two stored procedures to run at the same time, you could use [DBMS_LOCK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_LOCK.html#GUID-F1C17C14-6F79-435D-A959-D966EC0C7E0D) to get an exclusive lock (or just try to update the same row in a given table).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing for now, but I was confused about one proc having a job inside, and also when you use DBMS_LOCK you don't get the second call to stack up and wait and execute once the first is finished, correct? the proc running time isn't fixed and it is quite long, a few minutes (up to 5 I guess)

Comment: DBMS_LOCK with *exclusive* lock will wait: this should not be a problem if you have only 2 procedures (it will work with more than 2 procedures - but you cannot choose which next procedure will get the lock once it has been released).  If this does not work, please post your code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose the procedure [DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE_UNIQUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_LOCK.html#GUID-73F03FA6-04B3-4341-AB4F-8BECCF898D13) was designed.

Assign some unique `lockname` string and call the procedure at the beginning of the critical sequence in your procedure. You will get `lockhandle` as an output.

Then call `DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST` to start the unique processing

```
DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE_UNIQUE( v_lockname, v_lockhandle);    
v_res := DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST( lockhandle=>v_lockhandle, release_on_commit => TRUE);
```

At the end you must release the handle to be able to process the next run

```
v_res :=  DBMS_LOCK.RELEASE (v_lockhandle);
```

A good practice is to release it also in the EXCEPTION section to be not blocked after the failure.

Please check the possible options in the documentation such as for `release_on_commit` and adjust it for your need.

Some care should be taken with the return parameters of  the `REQUEST` and `RELEASE` procedures.